# How to create Windows 10 installation USB for a Mac without Bootcamp Assistant?

Tags: mac, windows-10, boot-camp

I'm trying to install Windows 10 x64 on a Mac Pro (3,1). The Mac doesn't have OS X installed so I don't have access to Bootcamp Assistant. I tried the following:

- Windows 7 USB DVD Download Tool

  - creates a NTFS USB and doesn't show up in Mac's boot selection screen (pressing `option` at boot)
- diskpart + xcopy

  - creates a FAT32 USB. It only shows `EFI Boot` (the UEFI boot) at the boot selection screen but not `Windows` (the MBR boot)

    [image]

Did I miss something obvious here?

Comment: Since you have acess to a Windows machine, since you running the Windows 7 tool, instead just use the Windows 10 version of the tool its called Media Creation Tool and is on the Microsoft website.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I gave it a spin and it seemed can only download the setup .iso but not using a local .iso? I have an enterprise x64 iso so probably won't have luck with the Media Creation Tool.

Comment: There are no Boot Camp drivers for Win10 on a  a 3,1 even if you can manage to force the USB installer. I never ever had any luck with anything other than a DVD installer on my old 3,1 so I would be very interested in any workarounds this question finds.

Comment: @Tetsujin, that's what I eventually did. I burned a Windows 10 DVD. I've been using Boot Camp 4.0.3131 since Windows 8 and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer here - https://youtu.be/qfqLmaesPvE
4 minute video. Basically, don't format as FAT32 and use this command prompt in terminal:

```
cp -rp /Volumes/CCCOMA_X64FRE_EN-US_DV9/* /Volumes/WINDOWS10/
```